# compliance with the proportions of the rubber (compressible) image

Tags: css, image, flexbox, responsive

There is a basic flexbox A container with a column direction, it contains several pairs of flexbox B containers with a row direction, which contain text and an image.When adding new elements to container A, the images are compressed, but with strong compression across the width of container A, the image loses its proportions.
aspect-ratio makes the container incompressible along the axis where the auto value is specified.
When using padding-bottom for proportions, the image is not displayed

Styles Container A

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-between;
gap:12px;
padding-left:32px;
padding-right:32px;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Styles Container with pairs

```
flex:1;
display:flex;
gap:12px;
```

Styles Container B

```
background-color:var(--AltColor);
border-radius:12px;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
flex:1 0 0;
color:var(--TextMainColor);
padding:8px;
```

Img with wrapper

```
<div style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
    <img src={props.img} style={{height:'0',minHeight:'100%',backgroundColor:'var(--ThemeColor)',maxWidth:'100%'}}/>
</div>
```

I will ask you not to offer a solution via rem, vw, vh.
also, the picture should be represented by the img tag

[Container without strong compression in width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJP0D.png)

[Container with strong compression in width (the proportions of width and height of the img tag are violated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO49A.png)

I tried using aspect ratio on img wrapper, but with it the picture becomes incompressible
when using padding-bottom:100% for proportions, height is explicitly specified:0, and I think that's why the picture is not displayed

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: What is the part with the curly braces? You should only show the generated HTML and CSS.